# working of Variable time amplitude amplification (VTAA) compared to amplitude amplification (AA)

Tags: quantum-algorithms, linear-algebra, grovers-algorithm, amplitude-amplification

I read the paper by Ambianis on [variable time amplitude amplification](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1010.4458.pdf) to improve the $\kappa$ (condition number) dependency for the Quantum linear system algorithm by [Childs et al.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.02306.pdf).

I can see [VTAA](https://www.lu.lv/fileadmin/user_upload/lu_portal/projekti/datorzinatnes_pielietojumi/publikacijas/konferences/Ambainis_6_3.pdf) perform well compared to AA as it relies on the fact that a probabilistic algorithm can take different completion times for the same input (due to different lengths of different computational branches).
[image]

> I am unable to understand how VTAA exploits this fact to improve the runtime from $O(1/\sqrt{\epsilon})T_{max}$ to $\tilde{O}(1/\sqrt{\epsilon})T_{avg}$, where, $T_{avg} = \sqrt{\sum_i{p_iT_i^2}}$.

I feel an ancillary qubit is kept (as a flag) to condition the further execution of the amplification process. Thus computation stops before
the worst case  of $O(\sqrt{n})$ steps/time.

> Is there some criteria where VAA is better choice over AA?